# Spring autowiring fails in RESTeasy service

Tags: spring, jboss, resteasy

I have a simple service which fails to autowire bean.
Although getting the same bean through context succeeds.
So the bean creation and registration in repository is working, but autowiring does not.
Changing class of the field in the service (`MyRepository` -> `YourRepository`), there is an error thrown that such bean does not exists, so the autowiring mechanism is working.

Any ideas what might be missing?

```
@Component
@Path("/")
public class RestService {

    @Autowired 
    private MyRepository myRepository; // is not autowired and is null

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response printMessage(@PathParam("param") String msg) {
        return Response.ok(
    AppContext.getContext().getBean("myRepository") == myRepository)
              .build(); // false
    }

    public void setMyRepository(MyRepository myRepository) {
        this.myRepository = myRepository;
    }
}
```

`AppContext` above is my simple implementation of `ApplicationContextAware`

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends MongoRepository<MyEntity, String> {

}
```

There is no .xml configuration and spring is initialized through

```
public class MyInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        container.addListener(new ResteasyBootstrap());

        final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ContextLoaderListener springListener = new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext);
        rootContext.register(MyConfiguration.class);
        container.addListener(springListener);
    }
}
```

And configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories("my.package.repository")
@ComponentScan("my.package")
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws UnknownHostException {
        return new MongoTemplate(new MongoClient("localhost"), "db");
    }
}
```

**EDIT after 2 comments**

I'm using the following library for RESTeasy - spring integration.
Do I need some other?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-spring</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

I think JAX-RS and RESTeasy is working correctly, because service is working and I can access it through web when deployed on JBoss

**EDIT for workaround**

Service is initialized correctly if I create the following constructor, but it feels more like a workaround

```
public RestService() {
    this.myRepository = MyContext.getContext().getBean(MyRepository.class);
}
```

And MyContext class for more clarity

```
@Component
public class MyContext implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;   
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

Comment: Spring will not inject `null` into your fields. If the field is `null`, then the object is not managed by Spring. Do you have the proper Spring/JAX-RS support libraries?

Comment: I am pretty sure that you are missing some things in MyInitializer that handle the integration between RestEasy and Spring. Unfortunately I don't know exactly what because I have only ever done that integration using a web.xml file

Comment: @geoand could you provide an example web.xml which is working for you? I've seen countless of them on the web and they all differ

Comment: @P. Šileikis did you get this working I have a very similar issue and I am wondering how you solved it or worked around it

Comment: @K2J not really, in the end we removed spring altogether and are just using plain jee with jboss container. In this case resteasy is working perfectly and is easy to setup.

Answer (score 2):

Spring might be setup correctly, but that doesn't necessary mean that Spring+RestEasy integration is setup correctly.

The code I am posting is the web.xml configuration that I have used (with RestEasy 3.0.6 and Spring 3.2.8) and correctly sets up the integration between RestEasy and Spring and also sets up Spring MVC (everything under /api is handled by RestEasy, everything else is handled by Spring MVC).

```
<web-app version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>my.package.config.ApplicationConfig</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>web</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/api</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring + RESTEasy -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- RESTEasy Servlet-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring MVC Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>my.package.config.MvcConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file></welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2):

Managed to solve the issue myself.

The correct solution is either to replace

```
public class MyInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        container.addListener(new ResteasyBootstrap());

        final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ContextLoaderListener springListener = new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext);
        rootContext.register(MyConfiguration.class);
        container.addListener(springListener);
    }
}
```

with

```
public class MyInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        container.addListener(new ResteasyBootstrap());

        container.addListener(new SpringContextLoaderListener());
    }
}
```

but in this case I'm losing possibility to use `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext`.
Also the initializer can be changed as follows to preserve annotation context.

```
public class MyInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        container.addListener(new ResteasyBootstrap());

        final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ContextLoaderListener springListener = new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext) {
            @Override
            protected ContextLoader createContextLoader() {
                return new SpringContextLoader();
            }
        };
        rootContext.register(MyConfiguration.class);
        container.addListener(springListener);
    }
}
```